# Is there any gravitational force between two stationary neutrinos, a billion light years apart?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, mass, mass-energy

Gravity is supposed to act over an infinite distance.  But if the force is very weak (due to low masses) and the distance is very far, is the force actually 0?  Or is the force so low that it is masked by random fluctuations in the quantum foam between the two particles?

Answer (score 1):

"Masked by fluctuations" is philosophically different from "is exactly zero." There would be a nonzero gravitational force which would be impossible to measure except in an empty universe.

Comment: If it is impossible to measure, then how do you know it's there?

Comment: @Jiminion if your well-tested theory _says_ it's there then you carry on as if it was actually there... until somebody comes along and pokes a hole in your theory.  Or, until somebody comes along and replaces your theory with a more satisfactory one that says it isn't there.

Comment: @Jiminion  If instead of the neutrinos you had two huge galaxies, the attraction had some chance to be better felt, and not masked. Now, the nature doesn't suffer of *duplication of personality*, it acts in the same way. If for big bodies there is attraction, so it is for small ones, but much weaker.

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute values in a nature. So, there is no absolute zero gravity between any (gravitating) particle in the universe. Assuming gravity is quantized, we could conclude that there is could be two particles in the universe that never exchanged any quant of gravity, but the probability of this event will never fall to absolute zero.

Comment: The first sentence seems a little philosophical (and not necessarily correct).